# Show that $\frac1n\log X_n$ converges almost surely

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, uniform-distribution, poisson-distribution, central-limit-theorem

> Let $X_0$ follow $\mathrm{Uniform}(0,1)$. Define $X_{n+1}$ iteratively as $X_{n+1}$ follows $\mathrm{Uniform}(0,X_n)$, $n\geq0$. Show that $\dfrac{\log X_n}{n}$ converges almost surely and find the limit.

I believe the limit is $0$. I tried to show that for any $\epsilon>0$ , $\sum_{i=0}^\infty P(|\dfrac{\log X_n}{n}|>\epsilon)<\infty$. However, I found that if $F_n$ is allowed to be the distribution function of $X_n$ then $$F_n(x)=x\sum_{i=0}^n\dfrac{(-\log x)^i}{i!}$$for $x\in(0,1)$. Now $F_n(e^{-n\epsilon})\to1$ (using Central Limit Theorem with $\mathrm{Poisson}(n\epsilon)$) so the series $\sum_{i=0}^\infty P(|\dfrac{\log X_n}{n}|>\epsilon)$ does not converge.

How can one show almost sure convergence?

Comment: Simpler: $X_n=X_0Y_1\cdots Y_n$ with $(Y_n)$ i.i.d. uniform on $(0,1)$, thus $\frac1n\log X_n=\frac1n\log X_0+\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\log Y_k\to E(\log Y)$ almost surely, with $E(\log Y)=$ $____$.

Comment: I did not know this result relating $X_n$ and $X_0$. Thank you.

Comment: ?? Isn't this the mere translation of the iterative construction in your post?

Comment: Is it? Although intuitive, it seems a bit non trivial to me. Will try to prove it.

Comment: @Did I just see a rectangle in front of $E(\log Y)$. What is that about?

Comment: @Cupitor A frame you are supposed to fill with the correct result.

Comment: @Did haha! I see....which I assume is zero!

Comment: @Cupitor The expectation of a negative random variable, zero? Not so sure.

Comment: @Did well $E(\log Y)=H(Y)$ where $H$ is the entropy function. I see it is 1! Thank you!

Comment: How did you construct that $X_n = X_0Y_1...Y_n$ where $Y_n$ are uniform on (0,1)?